# Stripe checkout integration in Android

Tags: javascript, android, webview, stripe-payments

I'm trying to integrate Stripe checkout in an android application. Currently I'm receiving the checkout session ID from the backend . I need to run this js code in application

```js
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<script>
  var stripe = Stripe('publishable_key')

  stripe.redirectToCheckout({
    sessionId:session.id

    })
</script>
```

In web , this code redirects to a page hosted in Stripe . How to achieve the same in android .I was advised against webview by the Stripe support as that solution appears to have some issues . How to proceed further from here .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not wish to use a `WebView` then your only option is to use the Stripe android SDK. There is no other way to run `js` code in android directly. Especially since this code simply redirects to Stripe gateway which will require a WebView.

Stripe has proper documentation on steps to be followed at https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=android. You will still need to perform some operations on your backend depending on your use-case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer . In case if we use the webview , how are we going to detect if the purpose of the webview is complete and close the webview .  For instance - if the payment is complete , how will we detect that so that we can close the webview

Comment: @newbie_coder I am not sure of how exactly stripe handles payments but you will need to have a webpage of your own which opens stripe and is called again after payment from stripe. You can try something like what [RazorPay recommends](https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/web-integration/standard/webview/). Do note that this will still need a lot of work and customization as webview doesn't allow multiple windows by default and payment gateways normally open the bank page on a new window (Please upvote the answer if it helped)

Comment: To clarify a bit, your own webpage (which gets loaded after payment) will be responsible for communicating with android using a `JavaScriptInterface`. You might be able to launch stripe's page directly on the webview but you will certainly need a webpage of your own to receive the payment status and communicate it with the app.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I don't have enough reputation to upvote .

Comment: @newbie_coder Not a problem. If my answer solved the issue, make sure you [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234).